# java jsch SSH_MSG_DISCONNECT Failed to read binary packet data

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

So I use a private key to connect to the sftp server ,so it came back error:

```
 com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: SSH_MSG_DISCONNECT: 2 Failed to read binary packet data!
```

Here is the code:

```
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    jsch.addIdentity(new File(privateKey).getAbsolutePath());
    session = jsch.getSession(ftpUserName, ftpHost, ftpPort);
    LOGGER.debug("Session created.");
    if (ftpPassword != null) {
        session.setPassword(ftpPassword);
    }
    Properties config = new Properties();
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.setConfig(config);
    session.setTimeout(timeout);
    session.connect();
```

is there anything in my code or i missed something?thank you.

Comment: I guess that exception is not thrown in the posted code block

Comment: Thank you ,finally it works,I just add`config.put("PreferredAuthentications", "publickey");`